# Type safety: Unchecked cast from Jugadores to Set<Jugador>

Tags: java, classcastexception

I must create a program with this method:

```
private static Set<Jugador>cargarJugadores(String f) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException
    {
        ObjectInputStream entrada=null;     

        Set<Jugador>listaDeJugadores=null;


        //entrada= new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        try
        {

            entrada=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));


            //Error here
            listaDeJugadores=(Set<Jugador>) new Jugadores();

            byte numDePuntuaciones;

            while(entrada.readObject()!=null)
            {

                listaDeJugadores.add((Jugador)entrada.readObject());

                numDePuntuaciones=entrada.readByte();

                for(int i=0;i<numDePuntuaciones;i++)
                {
                    listaDeJugadores.add((Jugador)entrada.readObject());
                }
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(InvalidClassException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try 
            {
                if(entrada!=null)
                    entrada.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       

        return listaDeJugadores;
    }
```

But i recived this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Jugadores cannot be cast to java.util.Set
    at JuegoAsteroides.cargarJugadores(JuegoAsteroides.java:340)
    at JuegoAsteroides.main(JuegoAsteroides.java:36)
```

I was hours trying fixed it but i didnt get it. Please I need help.

Comment: Where is class `Jugadores` and does it implement `Set`?

Answer (score 0):

`--Error--> listaDeJugadores=(Set) new Jugadores();`

fix this like this

`listaDeJugadores=new HashSet<Jugador>();`

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly casting a `Jugador` to a `Set<Jugador>`. In order to fix that, you want to initialize your `listaDeJugadores` to an instance of something that implements `Set`, which you place `Jugador` objects in...

So instead of this:
    `listaDeJugadores=(Set<Jugador>) new Jugadores();`

You want this:
    `listaDeJugadores = new HashSet<Jugador>();`